# How can you convert void* to a specific type in c#?

Tags: c#, pointers, .net-core, void-pointers

I have a series of classes, each built for a specific type (`Byte`, `UInt16`, `Double`, etc; each is defined by a `TypeCode`). Each class has nearly the same code, but does some casts to its specific type.
Note: there is a class member defined as: 
`void* _baseAddress;` and 
`ClassX* _table;`

A simplified example method:

```
    public unsafe UInt16 GetValue(int x)
    {
        return *((UInt16*) _baseAddress + (_table+ x)->entry);
    }
```

I want, assuming I have a class member called `MyType` which is defined by `typeof(inputType)`, to do this:

```
    public unsafe object GetValue(int x)
    {
        return *((MyType*) _baseAddress + (_table+ x)->entry);
    }
```

This clearly doesn't work.  I've been trying to read up on use of `Func` and `delegates` but keeping hitting a wall that a void* can't be converted like I want.

Because I think it adds context.  This is trying to *get* the value at a given location. I have a mirror method that should have:

```
*((MyType*) _baseAddress + (_table + x)->XEntry ) = inputValue;
```

Note: performance is important. I cannot allocate new memory, nor can I burn a bunch of processor time on the conversions

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this will accomplish what you want:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps the supplied byte array onto a structure of the specified type.
    /// </summary>
    public static T ToStructure<T>(byte[] data)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* p = &data[0])
            {
                return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(p), typeof(T));
            }
        };
    }
```

Which demonstrates the principle.  You should be able to adapt it to your specific purposes.

This function does the reverse operation:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the supplied object to a byte array.
    /// </summary>
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        int len = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
        byte[] arr = new byte[len];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return arr;
    }
```

`Marshal` is in `System.Runtime.InteropServices`.

If you need the absolute fastest possible speed, have a look [here](https://github.com/spazzarama/SharedMemory/blob/master/SharedMemory/FastStructure.cs).

You should also look at the [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Comment: I think one piece is missing, I tried something similar to this, but I really need the return to be T*, which isn't compileable. note this is because I need to add `+ (_table+ x)->entry` to the pointer value before de-addressing

Comment: Well, you can't use `T*` outside of an `unsafe` block.  Is it your intention to do that?

Comment: I don't think that's the error, it comes through as "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('T')", I think it's because T's size is indeterminate at compile time

Comment: Addresses/Pointers are only meaningful inside `unsafe` blocks.  Outside of those blocks, they are *references* or *value types*, *abstractions* over memory addresses.

Comment: I can declare the entire class as unsafe and the error persists.  `private unsafe T* MethodName()` is not valid c# as var as I can tell

Comment: I'm still not clear why you think you need `T*`.  Is it just so you can cast back to `Object`?  You can do that with the code I posted.

Comment: your `static T` example returns the object at the base of the memory. I have to do a calculation before getting the value at the (adjusted) memory location). your `static T` method gives the actual object at the given location, so I can't add my location-delta.

Comment: You would have to do it *inside* of the `unsafe` block.  In the code `private unsafe T* MethodName()`, `T*` is *not* inside the `unsafe` block.  And I'm still not sure that would work anyway.

Comment: In any case, I don't think you should be thinking about this in terms of `T*`; you're dealing with arbitrary memory locations, so there's no notion of type anyway.  Think in terms of `byte*` not `T*`.